# How to get extra fields from pivot table - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have create a Pivot model and table for laravel and added extra field to the pivot model. But the extra field is not displaying when calling pivot data.

I have a Customer model and Tag model. And a pivot called CustomerTag
Created a User with tags and added extra fiend to pivot table using

```
$user = User::create([
     'name' => 'User 1'
]);
$tag = 1;

$user->tags()->attach($tag, ['priority' => 1]);
```

But when I calling result

```
$use = User::find($id);
dd($user->tags->pivot);
```

The result doesn't have `priority` field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `withPivot` function when establishing the association on User model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'customer_tag', 'user_id', 'tag_id')
                ->withPivot('priority');
}
```

and then call it when getting the result:

```
$tags = $user->tags;
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $priority = $tag->pivot->priority;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In many to many relationship tags have multiple results

try

```
dd($user->tags[0]->pivot);
```

or use loop

```
 foreach ($user->tags as $tag){
    dd($tag->pivot);
 }
```